# How to extend webpack > config > externals in nuxt.config.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, rollupjs

So I need to set the alternative to `Rollup`'s `external` option (`external: path => /^three/.test( path )`) in `Webpack`

As I understand in `webpack` it's called `externals`, but I don't know how to set it in `extend (config, ctx) {}` in `nuxt.config.js`.

`config.module.externals = /^three/` doesn't seem to work, even though in webpack docs I've seen this example:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: /^(jquery|\$)$/i
};
```

My config in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
        /*
        ** You can extend webpack config here
        */
        extend (config, ctx) {
            config.module.rules.push(
                {
                    test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs|vert|frag)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: 'raw-loader'
                }
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I come to this since have same issue a hours ago, and this work for me :D

```
build: {
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      config.externals = function (context, request, callback) {
        if (/xlsx|canvg|pdfmake/.test(request)) {
          return callback(null, 'commonjs ' + request)
        }
        callback()
      }
    },
  },
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

so you don't need add config.module.external because the config is module it self

```
    build: {

      extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
        config.externals = [
          {
            // String
            react: 'react',
            // Object
            lodash: {
              commonjs: 'lodash',
              amd: 'lodash',
              root: '_', // indicates global variable
            },
            // [string]
            subtract: ['./math', 'subtract'],
          },
          // Function
          function ({ context, request }, callback) {
            if (/^yourregex$/.test(request)) {
              return callback(null, 'commonjs ' + request);
            }
            callback();
          },
          // Regex
          /^(jquery|\$)$/i,
      ];
    },
  },
```